# Regenerate expired GitHub PAT on Actions and Packages

Tags: docker, github, docker-registry

I am using GitHub Actions & Packages from Beta. Yesterday, the PAT expired. That's why my GitHub Actions failed. There is a Regenerate button on `Profile > Developer Settings > Personal Access Token`. I clicked it and created a new PAT.

At this step, I am able to `login docker.pkg.github.com` and push the image to GitHub Registry.

But, I am getting an error message when I pull that image.

This is the error message:

```
Error response from daemon: unauthorized: Your request could not be authenticated
by the GitHub Packages service.  Please ensure your access token is valid and has
the appropriate scopes configured.
```

How can I solve this expired PAT issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug and reported on the GitHub community https://github.community/t/bug-report-personal-access-tokens/147968/2

The `shell` stores your old token and doesn't update it. That's why you have to `logout` first for one time.

The solution:

1. Regenerate or Create a new Personal Access Token
2. Update your repo's Secret
3. in a `shell`, `docker logout https://docker.pkg.github.com`
4. in a `shell`, `docker login https://docker.pkg.github.com -u GITHUBUSERNAME`
5. use the new token as the password

Then you will able to pull an image from the GitHub registry as always.

I got the answer from zsoobhan-tc's post.